# Java Custom Annotations

Tags: java

I would want to create a custom annotation which would read the method name it was annotated. For instance, as given in the below example we don't pass the method getResult as value parameter to @Override annotation, but still Java recognizes the method name and it validates whether the method is defined at interface.

```
@Override
public int getResult()
```

Similar to this, if I write a custom annotation as specified in the example below, then my annotation would like to read the method name and invoke this method using Reflection.

```
@MyAnnotation
public int getResult()
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Annotations don't **do** anything on their own. They are simply data markers that *some other code* can read and change its behaviour accordingly.

Comment: You’ll need to be more specific. Which part are you struggling with? Reading the annotation from the field with reflection or something else?

Comment: Thanks SotiriosDelimanolis @JoachimSauer. Actually, I wanted to implement some custom annotation where if the custom annotation is enabled then execute the code inside that method, if not dont execute - without if else blocks in the method. Is it possible? Eg:
`
@CodeEnabled (True || False)
public int getResult()
`
The code in method is executed when the flag is true. Similar to the one in this article - https://mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/ . Without iterating each methods in Class, execute method with annotation and value true when the method is called.

Comment: Basically, I would want to implement feature toggle using custom annotation. Execute my code if feature is ON. Switch ON/OFF feature is done through custom annotation, rather than adding if else inside code.

Comment: The article actually explains really well how to read and react to the annotations. What you have to understand is that **some code** will need to read that annotation and have the if-else in there that you're trying to avoid. The advantage of annotations is not to avoid that entirely, but that it can be centralized in one placed and used multiple times. But you're not going to write *less code* if you only use it once. It **will** be more complex in that case.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I am trying to achieve here. If I pass a parameter like feature1, feature2 and have some common piece of code that validates this annotation and inside that it evaluates this feature is TRUE or FALSE and returns accordingly. So, my methods will have something like,. @CodeEnabled("feature"), @CodeEnabled("feature2") public int getResult()